Adding custom transition to WordPress Elementor Pro Menu
I have this WordPress site for personal project. my wp site I am using Elementor site builder. I built this MegaMenu with Elementor Menu widget. I am trying to add linear transition to submenu. It applies on submenu open but I cant get slide up transition when submenu closes. I tried several approaches including CSS, JS and GSAP library, but somehow Elementor blocks transition on mouse leave/submenu close. I tried the GSAP on code pen and it works fine. Here is the link But Elementor blocks transition out. I even used !important on my css.
I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.
This is my latest code on that WordPress site for this MegaMenu. I dont have any JS code for this menu since Elementor menu widget handles all JS.
.e-n-menu-content {
    transform: scaleY(0) !important;
    transition: transform 0.7s linear !important;
}

.e-n-menu-item:hover .e-n-menu-content{
    transform: scaleY(1) !important;
    transform-origin: top !important;
}

.e-n-menu-item:not(:hover) .e-n-menu-content{
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom !important;
}


The sub-menus are hidden via display: none, when their button is not hovered - so you would have to overwrite that, because trying to transform an element that is not shown, is of course pointless.

Hi C3roe, I tried display property previously with JS code, setting it to block on hover, but it didnt work either. Submenu transition works fine when you hover over a menu item, and transition that I want works fine as well. The only thing is I want submenu to disappear with same transition but somehow I can not apply that. I am guessing Elementor Menu widget blocking part of my code.

The megamenu code itself is toggling the display value, so your attempts to do it with JS, probably simply got negated again. But trying to override the inline styling on those elements with display: flex, stops the menu from working ... so this will likely need some more modifications.

Thats true. That's why I removed all my JS code since Elementor Menu widget handles all the functionality. I just wanted to manipulate the syling with CSS only. I am going through Elementor megamenu css file to see if I can override any of its transition settings.

So I fixed the issue with below few lines of CSS code .elementor-widget-n-menu .e-n-menu-content>.e-con:not(.e-active){
display: flex !important;
}
.e-n-menu-content {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 0;
transition: max-height 700ms linear;
}
.e-n-menu-item:hover .e-n-menu-content {
max-height: 700px;
transition: max-height 700ms linear;
}
